# Simplified LDAP/AD Server on C#

Tags: c#, server, ldap

I've searched without much success to the simplest (and yet working) example of an LDAP/AD Server for C#. Many libraries exist to connect to LDAP servers, ***but not the LDAP Server by itself (on C#)***.

I found however some information about it and even a post requesting a simple LDAP server that was answered "[LDAP isn't simple](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d1473dc-b58f-4211-9f55-77c1e5765ea2/is-it-possible-to-build-a-simple-ldap-server-by-using-c?forum=netfxbcl)"; and yet i read a lot of the RFC4511 and this sample code at GitHub [Flexinet LDAP Server](https://github.com/vforteli/Flexinets.Ldap.Server/blob/master/LdapServer.cs), but unfortunatly i don't have yet the knowledge to complete it's code.

My goal is **not to make** a fully functional LDAP server, but one that can at least do:

1. Serve as a login pool for softwares that allow it's users to be
   registered and log on a AD/LDAP server (just check for login and
   password for authentication).
2. Allow softwares like Outlook and Thunderbird to get a list of users (without passwords) with first and last name, e-mail address, phone number and department for contact list model.
3. No delete, add (or create), move, and other
   functions are required since the main software that i aim to
   integrate it with will do all the user and group management.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to implement the Flexinet sample and adjust to that functionalities; as form of a question what should i do to change this function to prevent it from causing an exception (on the "*var filter = searchRequest.ChildAttributes[6]*;" line it always breaks) when i call from a LDAP client software:

```
private void HandleSearchRequest(NetworkStream stream, LdapPacket requestPacket)
        {
            var searchRequest = requestPacket.ChildAttributes.SingleOrDefault(o => o.LdapOperation == LdapOperation.SearchRequest);
            var filter = searchRequest.ChildAttributes[6];

            if ((LdapFilterChoice)filter.ContextType == LdapFilterChoice.equalityMatch && filter.ChildAttributes[0].GetValue<String>() == "sAMAccountName" && filter.ChildAttributes[1].GetValue<String>() == "testuser") // equalityMatch
            {
                var responseEntryPacket = new LdapPacket(requestPacket.MessageId);
                var searchResultEntry = new LdapAttribute(LdapOperation.SearchResultEntry);
                searchResultEntry.ChildAttributes.Add(new LdapAttribute(UniversalDataType.OctetString, "cn=testuser,cn=Users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=com"));
                searchResultEntry.ChildAttributes.Add(new LdapAttribute(UniversalDataType.Sequence));
                responseEntryPacket.ChildAttributes.Add(searchResultEntry);
                var responsEntryBytes = responseEntryPacket.GetBytes();
                stream.Write(responsEntryBytes, 0, responsEntryBytes.Length);
            }

            var responseDonePacket = new LdapPacket(requestPacket.MessageId);
            responseDonePacket.ChildAttributes.Add(new LdapResultAttribute(LdapOperation.SearchResultDone, LdapResult.success));
            var responseDoneBytes = responseDonePacket.GetBytes();
            stream.Write(responseDoneBytes, 0, responseDoneBytes.Length);
        }
```

The code is on the github link.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: very well - i was asking if any other library (or project) that exists would fit that (that i could use), but for the implementation that i'm basing on, i'll edit above the part that i could not implement myself with success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i made a fork of the **Flexinet LDAP Server** on [@Sammuel-Miranda/LdapServerLib](https://github.com/Sammuel-Miranda/LdapServerLib) and with the author's support and some changes and adaptations i completed this implementation. It responds to the bind and search calls and works perfectly for **Outlook** and **Thunderbird** to use as a shared address book.

I did not implemente however any **ADD/MODIFY/DELETE** request (but would not be hard to do) since i don't need then.

Comment: Good job. Is this library supports ssl/tls or not?

Comment: i don't think i did - would have to look up a bit, but i don't beleave would be to big of a changed to support it

Comment: Ok, I think I need to work with `TcpListener SslStream class` to achieve this, is that correct?

Comment: in a way yes, would need that too - i have a chat server that uses a TcpListener with SSL so the approach would be similar, but the RFC4511 has also to identify the SSL request as is expected on the documentation, get the "saslBindInProgress" status code to use change "AuthenticationChoice" to include SaslCredentials and so on (i use it to guide development on this: [RFC4511](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4511#section-4.2)

Answer (score 1):

I found on the RFC4511 the explanation on how the search works ... and i'm "kind" of understanding it, not very well - and i see that the method implemented on the [GitHub from Flexinet LDAP Server](https://github.com/vforteli/Flexinets.Ldap.Server/blob/master/LdapServer.cs) only answer to bind and search requests of one single user (since it's only a example implementation).

The client is requesting diferent calls to verify capabilities, structure and other info before making the search request itself. So i'll implement it all, one by one.

Still, if any other lib (in C#) exists, and anyone know about, would be better than writing a hole new server. If my implementation works, i'll fork it on github and share.

Comment: i'm not beeing lucky in my implementation, but it's evolving - slowly ...